# How to use HttpContext.Current in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I need to get `HttpContext.Current` and `HostingEnvironment` in a class `EmployeeDataAccessLayer` in `AddEmployee` function. I have written below code now I am facing a problem that how can I call/use the function `AddEmployee` in my `controller`.

Now, as I have created 2 new `constructors` with parameters `IHttpContextAccessor` and `IHostingEnvironment` respectively causing me problem, I am not getting a proper way to use it.

```
    public class EmployeeDataAccessLayer 
        {
            private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
            private IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;        

            public EmployeeDataAccessLayer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
            {
                _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            }
            public EmployeeDataAccessLayer(IHostingEnvironment environment)
            {
                _hostingEnvironment = environment;
            }  
 public void AddEmployee(TblEmployee employee)
        {
            try
            {              
                string folderName = "UploadFile/";
                string sPath = "";
                sPath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "~/" + folderName);

                var hfc = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
}
```

I am following [this](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/01/05/accessing-httpcontext-asp-net-core/) article.

Comment: Don't. There's no global HttpContext any more. *Inject* the HttpContext instance from the controller if you *really* need it. In this case you don't - the data layer has no business accessing the *HTTP Request*. The controller should extract the data that should be written into the database and pass them as parameters to the data layer

Comment: In this case, this means that all injected interfaces should be removed from `EmpleyeeDataAccessLayer`. The `employee` *entity*, not table, should be configured by the controller and passed to `AddEmployee` for saving. If, for example, there's a need to store file names, the names should be created in the controller.

Comment: This is *supposed* to be a wake up call. One of the primary problems with statics is that they are often implicit dependencies. Dependency injection forces you to be explicit about your dependencies, and in this case, it should be readily apparent that your class is doing too much, breaking SOLID.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you haven't configured your controller to require an instance of EmployeeDataAccessLayer.

Be sure to register the EmployeeDataAccessLayer as a dependency like in the article you linked. Then your controller should take EmployeeDataAccessLayer as a constructor argument, you will store that as a readonly field and use it in your controller action. Then you should see that EmployeeDataAccessLayer has an instance of IHttpContextAccessor provided.

See a more complete example as the one you link is not complete(e.g. [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1) from microsoft).

As a side note, in your EmployeeDataAccessLayer you probably should not require the IHttpContext dependency if possible as others have mentioned in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Try using interface as follows :

```
 //controller
 public class HomeController
    {
      private readonly IDataAccess _dataAccess;

      public HomeController(IDataAccess dataAccess)
      {
        _dataAccess = dataAccess;
      }

      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Index(TblEmployee employee)
      {
       _dataAccess.AddEmployee(employee);
        return View();
      }
    }

 // Startup
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     // add dependency
     services.AddScoped<IDataAccess, EmployeeDataAccessLayer>();
     services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
 }

 // Data Access Impl
 public class EmployeeDataAccessLayer : IDataAccess 
        {
            private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
            private IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;        

            public EmployeeDataAccessLayer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
            {
                _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            }
            public EmployeeDataAccessLayer(IHostingEnvironment environment)
            {
                _hostingEnvironment = environment;
            }  
 public void AddEmployee(TblEmployee employee)
        {
            try
            {              
                string folderName = "UploadFile/";
                string sPath = "";
                sPath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "~/" + folderName);

                var hfc = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
           catch{}
      }  
 }
// interface
public interface  IDataAccess
{
 void AddEmployee(TblEmployee employee);
}
```

Another ugly approach (Using service locator):

if you don't want DI and constructor, you can use service locator as follows:

```
public static class MyServiceLocator
{
    public static IServiceProvider Instance { get; set; }
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    MyServiceLocator.Instance = app.ApplicationServices;
}


 // Data Access
 public class EmployeeDataAccessLayer  
        {         

        public void AddEmployee(TblEmployee employee)
        {
            try
            {      

                IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor =MyServiceLocator.Instance.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
                IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment=MyServiceLocator.Instance.GetService<IHostingEnvironment>();; 


                string folderName = "UploadFile/";
                string sPath = "";
                sPath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "~/" + folderName);

                var hfc = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
           } 
          catch{}
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Anupam, seems the solutions for my problem, but m unable to call api functions if I create constructor for controller, can't we implement interface in some other way..?

Comment: getting error 'the non-generic iServiceprovider(Type) can not be used with type arguments'